# Access Query form to two diferent tables. how to?

Tags: ms-access

I have two different tables (Stock and Sales), that begin with 4 similar columns.

Similar Columns: Date, Store, Product_Number, Product_Descipt.

All of these columns have relationships to their masters tables (except for date).

Then i have in the 'Stock table' the Stock_quantity column and in 'sales table' Sales_Quantity column.

I need to create a query that gives me all the 'similar columns' and the stock_quantity and sales quantity if they exist in that day!

The problem is, by example, if date doesn't exist in one of the tables that 'row' doesn't appear in the query even if it exists in the other table!

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a Union Query like this:

```
SELECT Date, Store, Product_Number, Product_Descipt, Stock_quantity as Quantity FROM Stock 
UNION 
SELECT Date, Store, Product_Number, Product_Descipt, Sales_quantity as Quantity FROM Sales
```

Edit: 
Sales_quantity and Stock_quantity in the same line for the same product:

```
SELECT Sales.Product_Number as Product_Number, Stock_quantity, Sales_quantity 
FROM Sales FULL OUTER JOIN Stock ON Sales.Product_Number = Stock.Product_Number;
```

Comment: Hi Mehdi. First of all thanks for your reply! The thing is i need to stock_quantity and sales_quantity in the same line. Is this possible? Thnaks a lot!

Comment: For the same Product ?

Comment: Please check the Edit

Comment: Hi Medhi. Yes for the same product, but like this "Date, Store, Product_Number, Product_Descipt, Stock_quantity, Sales_quantity". The problem is that the result is only gives me the "stock" or sales where "Date, Store, Product_Number, Product_Descipt" exists in both tables, and i need all even if the stock or sales dont exist (should return zero or empty). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah okay, you can use a FULL OUTER JOIN